# Adding content to tinymce by clicking the radio button in a lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to add contents(Value of the radio button), to the TinyMce by clicking a radio button in the light box.

The following code generates a list in the light  box with radio buttons:

```
foreach ($inventory_array_values as $key => $row) { //echo'<pre>'; print_r($inventory_array_values); echo'</pre>'; exit();?>
                            <ul class="<?php echo $rowcls; ?>" >
                                <li  style="width:10%">
                                <?php
                                    $arr = array('model' => $row[7],
                                                 'make'  => $row[6],
                                                 'year'  => $row[5],
                                                 'stock' => $row[3],
                                                 'vin'   => $row[2],
                                                 'color'  => $row[12],
                                                 'cartype' => $row[23],
                                                 'doors' => $row[32],
                                                 'style' => $row[9],
                                                 'transmission' => $row[10],
                                                 'intcolor' => $row[12],
                                                 'extcolor' => $row[13],
                                                 'priceselling' => $row[16],
                                                 'trimdesc' => $row[8],
                                                  'date_sold' => date('m-d-Y')
                                                );
                                ?>
                                     <input type="radio" name="inventorylink" onclick="call()" id="invValue" value="<?php echo $row[28]; ?>"></li>
                                <li  class="stock" style="width:20%"> <?= $row[3]; ?> </li>
                                <li  class="make"  style="width:25%"> <?= $row[6]; ?> </li>
                                <li  class="model" style="width:20%" title="<?= $row[7]; ?>" > <?php echo substr($row[7], 0, 10); ?> </li>
                                <li  class="color" style="width:15%"> <?= $row[12] ?> </li>
                            </ul>
                            <?php
                                $rowcls = ($rowcls == 'row1') ? 'row2' : 'row1';
                        } ?>
```

Using javascript I got the values of the radio buttons. The JS code is as follows:

```
function getRVBN(n) {
    var i, r = document.getElementsByName(n);
    for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (r[i].checked) return r[i].value;
    }
    return '';
    }


function call(){
    var value = getRVBN('inventorylink');
    alert('added');
}
```

Now I am trying to insert this value in a tinyMce editor. I tried all the possible ways like `tinyMCE.get('my_editor').setContent(data);` and `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);` but nothing worked. I dono where I am going wrong. Any help with this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The following code helps to add the multiple values to the tinymce editor:

```
function call(){
    var value = getVBN('inventorylink');
    top.window.tinymce.get('nwemail').getBody().innerHTML = top.window.tinymce.get('nwemail').getBody().innerHTML + value;
}
```

If just only one value is to be added, use it as follows:

```
function call(){
    var value = getVBN('inventorylink');
    top.window.tinymce.get('nwemail').getBody().innerHTML = value;
}
```